# wait a process to finish in Python script

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm writing a Python script to run several executables one by one on Windows. I need to wait a program to finish before starting the next.

So the script will be like this.

```
1: launch a.exe
2: wait till a.exe finishes running
3: launch b.exe
4: wait till b.exe finishes
```

Anyone have an idea how to make the script waiting for a process to finish in Python?

Thanks

Comment: IMO You don't have to specially do anything, It just works the way you intend here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to wait for your launched process, you can simply use subprocess.call() . This method executes the command in args and waits for it to complete. For reference, see [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(('someprog.exe', str(i)))
```

Comment: If you want each one to complete, use `subprocess.check_call` to see if they were successful or not.